# How to see Current users on the system

Tags: linux, users

I need a script to identify only and only users ( current users ) on the system and what actions they are performing.

I use w , but don't show user's actions that are currently performing ... and PS shows me also the machine...

I need something that only shows users with their current job.

Comment: Maybe you just use `ps` wrongly and should have a look at its man page to understand how process selection by user works? You don't even give the `ps` command line you use. How shall one help you that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
who | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort | uniq | 
  while read user; do ps -u $user -o %u%c%a; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be klunky, but...

```
     for PERSON in $(who | grep -v USER | grep -v load | awk '{print $1}'); 
     do echo $PERSON
     ps -u $PERSON
     done
```